# How to use color code using json

Tags: android, json, textview, background-color

I am getting color code from server for my product listing,the color codes getting perfectly,but i am trying to set it in my `textview` but not able to set the `color`,following is my snippet code and `adapter`,any help will be appreciated.

The color code which i get from server

```
[
    {
        "colors": [
            "#000000",
            "#7E3517",
            "#C85A17"
        ],

    },
    {
        "
        "colors": [
            "#000000",
            "#C85A17"
        ],

    }
]
```

MainActivity.java

```
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... args) {
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(INTEREST_ACCEPT_URL, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonary = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    System.out.println("Test jsonObj"+jsonary);


                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonary.length(); i++) {
                        c = jsonary.getJSONObject(i);
                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_NAME, c.getString(INTERESTACCEPT_USER_NAME));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRICE,c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRICE));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_DISCOUNT, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_DISCOUNT));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRODUCTID, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_PRODUCTID));
                        map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGEURL, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_IMAGEURL));
                        //map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_AGE, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_AGE)+" years");
                        //map.put(INTEREST_ACCEPT_LOCATION, c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_LOCATION));
                        // adding HashList to ArrayList

                       JSONArray colors=c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);
                        JSONArray sizes=c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_SIZES);

                        user_img=c.getString(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);



                        user_img = "";
                        userImgArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        JSONArray picarray = c.getJSONArray(INTEREST_ACCEPT_COLOR);
                        for(int a=0;a< picarray.length();a++)
                        {
                            user_img = picarray.getString(a);
                            userImgArrayList.add(user_img);
                        }
                        Log.d("mylog", "curent color  = " + userImgArrayList);

                        if(userImgArrayList.size()==0) 
                        { 
                        Log.e("Size zero","No set color here"); 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==1) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second="#ffffff"; 
                        third="#ffffff"; 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==2) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second=userImgArrayList.get(1); 
                        third="#ffffff"; 

                        } 
                        else if(userImgArrayList.size()==3) 
                        { 
                        first=userImgArrayList.get(0); 
                        second=userImgArrayList.get(1); 
                        third=userImgArrayList.get(2); 

                        }
                        System.out.println("Color First"+first);
                       System.out.println("Color Second"+second);
                       System.out.println("Color Third"+third);
                       System.out.println("Color Fourth"+fourth);



                        data.add(map);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }
            return data;
        }
```

MyAdapter.java

```
  @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.product_listing_items, null);
               holder.propic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_img);
                holder.txtproname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_name);
                holder.txtprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productlist_price);
                holder.firstcolor = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.firstcolor);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.txtproname.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));
            holder.txtprice.setText(listData.get(position).get(TAG_PRICE));

           int firstcolor=0;
            firstcolor=Integer.parseInt(first);



            holder.firstcolor.setBackgroundColor((firstcolor));
```

Comment: It depends on the way your color is stored within your `JSONArray`... is it hex rgb?

Comment: the color code i have is #000000 in this format

Comment: @BartoszLipinski seee my edited question

Comment: You already got [the right answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33477838/1993204)

Comment: that answer is not working for me

Comment: yes this one is right http://stackoverflow.com/a/33477838/3134215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use it in this way(if it is hexcode like #000000, #ffffff)

```
holder.firstcolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(first));
```

argument for parseColor will accept String , so please carefull for that

Comment: but firstcolor is int,..see

Comment: yes @Lakhan i have corrected that, and mention it as well

Comment: it says java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "#000000"

Comment: first try it in static way like this "Color.parseColor("ffffff")" , then check for dynamic way

Comment: tried with this...         holder.firstcolor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
..still same error

Comment: yes it was mistake with my background xml..accepted and vote up